# Windows 10 Xampp Apache - htaccess rewriterule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am using `apache` `XAMPP` on `Windows 10` and am trying to get `htaccess` working. I have this so far...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^noexist/?$ /folder/
```

I want someone to go to

```
www.mysite.com/noexist/test.php -> www.mysite.com/folder/test.php
```

But I still want the URL to be [www.mysite.com/noexist/test.php](http://www.mysite.com/noexist/test.php)

I am just getting a 404, where am I going wrong? I have confirmed the htaccess file is being loaded by putting invalid code in and it throws an error so I am certain the file is being used.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^noexist/?$ /folder/
> ```

The regex `^noexist/?$` matches `noexist` or `noexist/` only, so `/noexist/test.php` is ignored by this rule. It also only rewrites to `/folder/` only.

In other words, this rewrites `/noexist` (or `/noexist/`) to `/folder/` only.

To rewrite `/noexist/<something>` to `/folder/<something>` then you need to capture the `<something>` part and pass this through to the target URL (i.e the *substitution* string). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^noexist/(.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string contains the URL-path captured by the parenthesised subpattern (ie. `(.*)`) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Don't forget the `L` (`last`) flag. (This is important if you have other directives later in the file.)

Note that this rewrite is unconditional, regardless of whether `/folder/<something>` exists or not. If you want to check that `/folder/<something>` exists before rewriting then add an additional *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^noexist/(.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

This assumes your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root.